# Proper interpretation of convolution with product of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, distribution-theory, convolution

Suppose we have $\phi(x)\in C^\infty_c$ and:
$$\delta_a\{\phi\}=\int \delta(x-a)\phi(x)dx=\phi(a)$$
$$\delta_a*\phi=\phi(x-a)$$
The convolution leads to a shifting the input.

Suppose we multiply the integral by $f(x)\in C^\infty$:
$$\int \delta(x-a)\phi(x)f(x)dx=\phi(a)f(a)$$
I suppose the notation for this could be:
$$\delta_a\{\phi f\}=f(a)\delta_a\{\phi\}=\int\delta(x-a)f(a)\phi(x)dx$$
But for the convolution is it:
$$\delta_a*[\phi(x)f(x)] $$
or $$[f(a)\delta_a]*\phi(x) $$

I am pretty sure these expressions are not equivalent as the first shifts the product of the two while the second shifts $\phi$ but multiplies it by the value of $f(a)$. are both valid and just mean different things (ie we can choose whichever one we need)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you confused yourself by writing $\delta_a\{\phi f\} = f(a)\delta_a\{\phi\}$. This is technically true... but I'd prefer it if you wrote this instead as $\delta_a\{\phi f\} = f(a)\phi(a)$.

The convolution of the distribution $\delta_a$ against $\phi(x)f(x)\in C^{\infty}_0$, should be notated as $\delta_a * [\phi f]$. This is because
$$\delta_a * [\phi f] = \delta_{y-a}\{\phi(x-y)f(x-y)\} = \phi(x-a)f(x-a)$$ $$\overset{\text{if we abuse notation...}}{=}\int\delta(y-a)\phi(x-y)f(x-y)dy.$$
Note that the result $\phi(x-a)f(x-a)\in C^{\infty}_0$ as well.

Comment: thanks. so that is the first expression. is there any meaning to the second one, $[f(a)\delta_a]*\phi(x)$? is there any reason we couldn't make sense of this expression?

Comment: The second expression also makes sense! It is just not equal to $\delta_a * [f\phi]$. The second expression is the convolution of the distribution $f(a)\delta_a$ against $\phi$. This is notated as $f(a)\delta_a*[\phi]$.

Comment: thanks. so to wrap up: we can go from $\int\delta(x-a)\phi(x)f(x)dx$ to either $\delta_a*[f\phi]$ or $f(a)\delta_a*[\phi]$ and the interpretation of the two (different) convolutions are as in your answer/comment?

Comment: Yes, to be clear, we have $$\int \delta(x-a)\phi(x)f(x) dx = \delta_a\{\phi f\} = \phi(a)f(a),$$
$$\delta_a*[\phi f] = \int \delta(y-a)\phi(x-y)f(x-y) = \phi(x-a)f(x-a),$$
and
$$f(a)\delta_a*[\phi] = f(a)\left(\delta_a*[\phi]\right)=f(a)\int\delta(y-a)\phi(x-y) = f(a)\phi(x-a).$$